# WiFi disconnects periodically

Tags: networking, wireless, connection, 17.04

Every thirty minutes or so, my wifi seems to stop working (on one specific network). The network disconnects, and I usually have to restart the computer in order to get reconnected. The security is wpa2. Other devices in the range do not do the same.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
```

returns

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095b] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5210]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I added it.

Comment: This is still happening, can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

There are not any specifics to go on here, but I will offer an educated guess based on 11 years using UBUNTU and other Linux distributions. You say this is happening on just one of a field of wifi signals available to you. That suggests that the problem is upstream of your machine. I have run into similar glitches with wifi connected to providers with oversold bandwidth. Somehow the provider times you out and drops the connection. You can log back in when band width becomes available again on the provider's equipment. So, I don't think this is a problem with your hardware or software.

Comment: "other devices in the range do not do the same" suggesting it IS an issue with the device in question

Comment: Yeah, what do you mean by upstream of my machine?